# Can i create a facebook event from an app with any platform?

Tags: android, facebook, mobile

I have been  spending days looking for a method to create a facebook event with a mobile app or a web mobile one does any one know about a solution for me ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: It seems you cannot create events anymore with the new Graph API that Android apps should use. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/event

You need Facebook SDK for Android. You can find a sample of code to create an event here : [create facebook event in an android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639919/create-facebook-event-in-an-android-app)

Comment: Thank you but according to the official developers site https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog I cannot do it since 30 April 2014 do you suggest any other solution ?

Comment: As even the official doc explicitly says you can't, I believe you really can't. I can't think of any app I know that do that. Sorry...

Comment: Is there any way to create a group from Android app ??

Comment: From Android apparently not, but Facebook apps can: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/group#publish